# Влияние console.log на Деструктуризация без объявления при вычислении Фибоначчи на Node,js

Tags: node.js, деструктурирующее-присваивание

Можете объяснить как?! console.log может влиять на математический алгоритм?

Предисловие: на Pythone Фибоначчи выглядит так:

```
f1, f2 =  1 , 1
print(f1)
while f2 < 100:
    print(f2)
    f1, f2 = f2, f1+f2
```

Я захотел повторить этот алгоритм в питоновском стиле на NodeJS (у меня версия v10.16.2 под Windows), используя деструктуризацию без присвоения, вот рабочий код:

```
var [f1,f2] = [1,1]
while (f2 < 100) {
  console.log(f2)
  console.log('!');/* БЕЗ этого console.log вываливается с ошибкой 
                      [f1,f2] = [f2, f1+f2]
                              ^
                      TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
                      С console.log - работает 
                   */
  [f1,f2] = [f2, f1+f2]
}
```

Comment: Возможно вы просто не ставите точку с запятой после первого лога, и поэтому квадратные скобки ниже предполагаются относящимися к возвращаемому консоль-логом значению, которое undefined.

Comment: Извините, но вы по-русски говорить умеете? Заголовок нечитаем...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в точке с запятой после `console.log('!')`. Без неё ваш код парсится как `console.log(f2)[f1,f2] = [f2, f1+f2]`, то есть как `undefined[1] = [f2, f1+f2]`.

См. https://javascript.info/structure#semicolon

Лучше во избежание таких трудностей всегда заканчивать инструкции точкой с запятой.